# Does sforce.console.onFocusedPrimaryTab work? Does it work inside a publisher action?

Tags: api, service-cloud-console, servicecloud, global-actions

The [Salesforce Console Integration Tookit](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_console/index.htm) provides two functions for detecting switching focus of console tabs:

- `onFocusedPrimaryTab`
  http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_console/Content/sforce_api_console_onfocusedprimarytab.htm
- `onFocusedSubtab` http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_console/Content/sforce_api_console_onfocusedsubtab.htm

I've been working on a Custom Visualforce Global Action and I'm able to use `onFocusedSubtab` without any issue to detect focus.  However `onFocusedPrimaryTab` does not work in the same way.  I have tested both functions using the samples from the documentation and I have no errors in Chrome dev tools that would indicate the callback is not being registered with `onFocusedPrimaryTab`.

The documentation does not indicate that they should behave differently, the only subtle hint that they may be different is that `onFocusedSubtab` is in the "Methods for Primary Tabs and Subtabs" section of the docs whilst `onFocusedPrimaryTab` is in the "Methods for Application-Level Custom Console Components" section.  For this reason I tried hooking up a callback in the console from a Custom Console Component in the highlights panel (top of Service Console), but it still didn't work.

Sample code from the documentation:

```
<apex:page>
    <apex:includeScript value="/support/console/25.0/integration.js"/>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var eventHandler = function (result) {
            alert('Focus changed to a different primary tab. The primary tab ID is:' 
        + result.id + 'and the object Id is:' + result.objectId);
        };
        sforce.console.onFocusedPrimaryTab(eventHandler);
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Does anyone have any experience of `onFocusedPrimaryTab` working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `onFocusedPrimaryTab` function is available as one of the "Methods for Application-Level Custom Console Components".

I had tried to add a Visualforce page to the console via the Custom Console Component link for layouts e.g:

[image: Custom Console Component on layouts]

I actually needed to add a Custom Console Component via the App | Edit screen

[image: Adding Application Level Custom Console Components]

The answer to my question is that yes `onFocusedPrimaryTab` does work from the context of a Custom Console Component but it doesn't appear to work from within a Publisher Action (Quick Action).